# import twitter Not working, module twitter not found

Tags: python, twitter, import, module

I'm very new to the programming world, but it's getting always more and more fun.
I have almost completed a python course, and I'm just missing the last section.

The problem is that when I import twitter from pycharm edu (python 3.8.2) I get:

```
import twitter
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twitter'

I've installed pip3 install python-twitter;

I've tried also with pip3 install twitter, but nothing.

pip version is 20.0.2

python is 3.8.2

Comment: This is likely the classic issue of installing packages and running the program using different Python installations. Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: Can you successfully `import` it using the REPL?

Comment: The PyPI module `twitter` only supports up to Python 3.6 and is outdated. He is using Python 3.8.2. In the future when you are pip installing and you see error messages you should post them as well. Else people will assume the installation worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure your `pip3` and `python3` CLI refer to the same Python interpreter you are using you can do the following: `python3 -m pip install twitter`
You can check the python version with `python3 -V`. Your python path might be called `py`, `py3`  or `python`.

---

The `twitter` module is outdated and does not support python 3.8.2. See: https://pypi.org/project/twitter/
It supports Python 3.6.

I recommend you using tweepy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's a lot. I've installed tweepy at the end as suggested. I realized that in terminal package was working, so it was an issue with Pycharm. So went to preferences - python interpreter, and added installed the module in Pycharm.

As I said I have no experience, but it was good to learn so much about pip installation.